# Loading partial data in child object using hibernate projections

Tags: java, hibernate

```
class User{
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<Address> address ;
}

class Address{
    int id;
    String city;
    String state;   
}
```

I want to load partial data from Address class using hibernate criteria or HQL. In this case I only want to load address id and state from Address class. I realized I could partially load data using projections but I do not know what can be done about address class.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("id"),"id")
.add(Projections.property("firstName"),"firstName")
.add(Projections.property("address"),"address")
```

If I try to limit data loading in Address class using projections

```
.add(Projections.property("address.id"),"address.id")
```

I get error as there is not object address.id in user class. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used hibernate query language (HQL) to achieve the desired result.

First I instantiate user class and added a new constructor as shown below

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            String hql = "select new User(user.id, user.firstName, user.address.id, user.address.state " 
                    + "from User user where user.id in (:userIdList) ";
            Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
            q.setParameterList("userIdList",userIdList);
            userList=q.list();
            session.flush();
        }
```

Then we need to update the construtor of User as:

```
public User(int id, String firstName, int addressId, String state) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.address = new Address();
    this.address.setState(state);
    this.address.setId(addressId);
```

This will load only the data we desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class, say AddressId, which only contains a Long attribute. Map this new class properly to Address table. Add a list of AddressId to User class. Use projections to load this new list and not the other one.